# Why would static methods be considered "utility methods" in an interface?

Tags: java, static

I am reading the Java documentation about interfaces and reached the chapter about [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). As far as I understand, when you define an interface and later add methods to it, all classes that implement this interface will break and are in need of implementing the new method.

So the documentation briefly mentions static methods as an option to mitigate this problem, but also states, that they would be viewed as "utility methods" and not essential:

> If they add them as static methods, then programmers would regard them as **utility methods, not as essential, core methods**.

Why is this the case / why would they be viewed as "not essential"?

Comment: Because a `static` method is associated with a `class`; not an `instance`.

Comment: First you talk about default methods, then you talk about static methods. It's unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: @aioobe The chapter is about default methods, but then mentions static methods as another option to mitigate the breaking of implementing classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

static methods do not work on the instance of a class, but are part of the class itself. They are most often used for utility type of tasks and therefor a little bit contradict object-orientation so should be used sparsely.

But, default methods != static methods. The docs just mention the static methods there to show how before default methods something could have been added to an interface without breaking all implementations.

Default methods are another way to add functionality to an interface without breaking existing impementations by specifying a default implementation for that method (even if it is just a `throw new NotImplementedException()`). And these methods can be implemented by the concrete classes that implemented this interface to provide the actual functionality they are meant for and thus overriding the default implementation of the method.

With static methods this is not possible, as they belong to the class object, not the instance and thus cannot be overridden by subclasses or implementations.

Comment: So static methods in an interface are called "utility methods" just because people mostly use static methods as utility methods? (definition by tradition if you will...)

Comment: No, they are not called "utility methods" they are called "static methods". They just often are used as utility methods.

Comment: You're right, should have written "considered" instead of "called". My mistake.

Comment: Then, more or less, yes. It lies in the nature of static methods that they are mostly used as utility methods.

Comment: How do you define a "utility method"?

Comment: Well, anyone who mentions "utiltiy method" here which includes both you and @hamena314 :)

Comment: @aioobe The "definition" from the documentation proposes, that static methods in an interface are considered "utility methods" ... and I stated that this "definition" is made simply because people tend to use them as utility methods purely out of tradition. There is no hard definition that static methods ARE utility methods. Language is vague. :)

Comment: @aioobe ask Oracle, they used the term at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Because you call `static` methods generally on `class` not on the Interface, eg:

`Integer.parseInt();` - is called on concrete class `Integer`

Answer (score 2):

Because static methods are self-contained, they don't depend on other methods in an interface. And more over most of the static methods in java code are actually utility methods.

Comment: A static method does not need to be self-contained. It can use other static methods just fine.

Comment: And a static method in `SomeInterface` presumable works on `SomeInterface` objects, on which it can call all `SomeInterface` methods on.

Comment: Not really. A static method cannot call instance methods, as it does not know which instance it should call the method on.

Comment: @Vampire Yes, I meant that it can't call instance methods.